# python looping and appending to a list

Tags: python

I have a relatively small python program, which (partly) looks something like the following:

```
puredata=ClassOne()
stuff=ClassTwo()

for i in range(0,len(chunks)):
    print "this is in loop  i  = %d" % i
    temp=chunks[i]
    #do some stuff and get variable data.

    for k in range(0,len(data)):
        print "this is in loop  k  = %d" % k
        if puredata.tb in str(temp[k])!=False:
            print "This is valid data..continue calculations"
            puredata.pl,puredata.pt,puredata.pi=stuff.extracts(data[k])
            print "Length of pl puredata = %d" % len(puredata.pl)
            print "Length of pt puredata = %d" % len(puredata.pt)
            print "Length of pi puredata = %d" % len(puredata.pi)
        else:
            pass
```

The stuff.extracts() spits out 3 lists (something like self.a, self.b, self.c), which I then pass on to puredata.pl,puredata.pt,puredata.pi and ClassOne simply invokes the lists pl,pt,pi. ClassTwo looks something along the lines of:

```
class ClassTwo():
    def __init__(self):
      self.a=[]
      self.b=[]
      self.c=[]
# Start calculations
    def extracts(self,soup):
        # do stat modelling and calculations
          return self.a, self.b,self.c
```

When I run the loop, I find that data seems to "appended" to puredata.pl,puredata.pt,puredata.pi although I have never used the .append() anywhere in the code. So, in the first loop the length of puredata.pl,puredata.pt,puredata.pi is say 10, and in the next loop it becomes 20, then 30..and so on..

I am finding this very strange - and I am not able to make sense out of it. At some level, this is what I want (I mean the appending of data to a list), but I am baffled why it appends although I have not used .append().

Sorry if this is a kn00b question - python newbie here.

Comment: `if puredata.tb in str(temp[k])!=False:` is parsed as (I think):  `if (puredata.tb in str(temp[k]))!=False:` which makes it more or less equivalent to `if puredata.tb in str(temp[k])`:

Comment: @mgilson, yea I see what you mean - but I do not think that this is the reason I have an appended list without me asking it to append - do you think it is?

Comment: definitely not the problem.  It if was the problem, I would have posted that as an answer :).  It's just something that I found confusing while I was reading over the code and I thought I'd let you know that was a very strange statement.

Comment: @mgilson thats fine - I have changed that part of the code now. Still unsure why it would append all results to my list!

Comment: How are the lists returned from .extracts? Are they references or copies?

Comment: @JoakimGebart, the results from .extracts are 3 lists. So, I have something like: "return self.a, self.b,self.c" at the end of my extracts method. I am not sure what you exactly mean by references or copies - could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JoakimGebart: just added the skeleton structure of ClassTwo - if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mostly likely problem, based on what you have provided, is that the stuff.a stuff.b and stuff.c are growing each time you call stuff.extracts. If the stat modelling and calculations being performed in ClassTwo are unique to each data[k], then declaring stuff = ClassTwo() inside of the loop should resolve your problem.

e.g:

```
for k in range(0,len(data)):
    stuff = ClassTwo()
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip - what you say seem to make sense... thats the stuff.a,stuff.b and stuff.c seem to be growing every time. I will check this now.

Comment: You were correct - that is exactly what was happening. Putting the class inside the loop solved the problem! thanks again.